# JavaScript, how to keep proper encapsulation in place while using a singleton?

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces, singleton, encapsulation

I want to start structuring my JavaScript better so that I'm not polluting the global namespace as well as practice better encapsulation and inheritance as I described in this code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64556/42628

So, take this example ([here is a fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/p00r7tn2/6/))...

```
window.myPage = {
    init:function(){
        //local "Private" declarations
        var gridHandle1 = new myPage.MyGrid();
        gridHandle1.loadGridData();
    },
    MyGrid: function(){
        /* local "Private" declarations */
        var dataLoadTimes = 0;
        var gridDrawn = true;
        $('#debug').append('grid is drawn<br>');

        //This needs to be a public method because
        //other functions need to reload the grid
        //at various times. So I will use "this."
        //instead of "var".  "var" would make it a
        //private method.
        this.loadGridData = function() {
            dataLoadTimes = dataLoadTimes+1;
            $('#debug').append('grid data has been loaded '+dataLoadTimes+' times<br>');
        };

        this.loadGridData();
    }
};

myPage.init();
// console.log(gridHandle1); // <--- fails, GOOD, it's not in the global namespace
// console.log(gridDrawn); // <--- fails, GOOD, it's not in the global namespace
```

I understand everything going on here and I like it because "loadGridData" only pertains to "MyGrid", it has no business being it's own function outside of "MyGrid", that would break encapsulation.  But doing it this way requires this line...

`var gridHandle1 = new myPage.MyGrid();`

That's cool, it allows me to create many grids like this...

```
var gridHandle1 = new myPage.MyGrid();
var gridHandle2 = new myPage.MyGrid();
var gridHandle3 = new myPage.MyGrid();
```

But in this scenario I don't need many grids.  I only need one.  So my question is, how would I adjust this code so that everything works the same but do it as a singleton, NOT using the "class" way and instantiate an object using the constructor function?

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways to accomplish this and end the end it comes down to preference.

Personally I code like this:  (without jquery--I don't use it)

```
var myPage = {
  ua: {}
}

$(function() {
   myPage.mainLayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, "2U");
   myPage.mainTabBar = myPage.mainLayout.cells("b").attachTabbar();
   myPage.initTab(myPage.mainTabBar);
});


myPage.initTab=function(tb){  
   tb.xyz();
}: 


myPage.ua.load=function(id){
    myPage.ua.innerLayout = myPage.mainTabBar.tabs(id).attachLayout("1C");
    myPage.ua.grid        = myPage.ua.innerLayout.cells("a").attachGrid();
}

myPage.ua.search = function() {
    myPage.ua.grid.clearAndLoad([theUrl], "json");
};
```

Sometimes I define `ua` and sometime I keep everything tied to `myPgae`.

Comment: Thanks.  I completely re-worded my question so hopefully it's clearer.  I don't want to do it as you suggest because it breaks encapsulation. Search() should be a member function of its grid object, not a function standing out on it's own.  grid isn't var scoped so bleeds out so that search() can have access to it, etc...  Hopefully my updated question will make it clearer what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're going to find that trying to encapsulate variables and functions without creating objects is not worth the trouble (in javascirpt).  There's a lot written about it and it comes down to this:  if a user can create a variable, they can pretty much call any function, redefine the object and set variables contained therein.  You'll find yourself going down the route of defining closures which consume more memory than building objects with prototypes (which is the correct way to do what you've written above).  Being that you don't want to use objects, bottom line: it's a pain, not worth it.

Comment: Consider what you said: "Search() should be a member function" the only way to have members is to have an object.